# Open one Air app from another Air app on Android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, android-intent, air

I need to open one Air app from another Air app on Android. So far I tried three options all failed:

1. Open using `adobe.utils.ProductManager` described [here](http://blog.everythingflex.com/2009/06/08/open-an-air-application-from-a-2nd-air-application/), but I can't find the 'publisher id'. It's a very old article I didn't get my hopes up with this on.
2. Using `andoid:scheme`, works fine from browser, but from other Air app I get a 'Security Sandbox Violation'. I used this one in combination with a normal link and a redirecting page. Looks very unprofessional, but it works.

   ```
   navigateToURL(new URLRequest('air.com.developer.appname://'));
   ```
3. Using `intent:` described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22520218/opening-another-android-app-in-a-new-window-from-air), with the benefit of opening in a new task.

   ```
   var url:String = ("intent:#Intent;" +
                     "action=android.intent.action.MAIN;" +
                     "category=android.intent.category.LAUNCHER;" +
                     "launchFlags=0x10000000;" +
                     "component=<your-package-name>/.<your-activity-name>;" +
                     "end";
   navigateToURL(new URLRequest(url));
   ```

None of these work for me.

Last option looks like the best of all, but **I can't find my activity name**.

This is part of my manifest data:

```
<activity android:launchMode="standard">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="air.com.developer.appname" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If I try to add an `android:name` attribute to `<activity />` I get:

```
error 404: Android attribute android:name is not allowed to be overridden
```

Any way to find out the default `android:name` attribute? Or any other advice on how to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Flash Builder it will automatically give your activity a name. For intance, it gave my activity the name of .AppEntry so for the third case (intent by URI) I would have to enter the following:

```
    var url:String = ("intent:#Intent;" +
              "action=android.intent.action.MAIN;" +
              "category=android.intent.category.LAUNCHER;" +
              "launchFlags=0x10000000;" +
              "component=sebastianT.app.package/.AppEntry;" +
              "end";
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest(url));
```

I hope this helps.

EDIT

I downloaded an app called Memory Usage (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mem.usage&hl=es_419) and I was able to open it from my Air app using the following code:

```
            var url:String = ("intent:#Intent;" +
                "action=android.intent.action.MAIN;" +
                "category=android.intent.category.LAUNCHER;" +
                "component=mem.usage/.activity.MainActivity;" +
                "end");
            navigateToURL(new URLRequest(url));
```