# how to open an Instagram page by as3 in android air application?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

i want open an instagram page by clicking on a button in my app, for example "instagram/mypage" in Instagram app.
whats the code?

```
mybuttun.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, open_instagram_page);
function open_instagram_page(event:MouseEvent)
{
    //what should i write here?
}
```

i found this code that open "setting" page of android device,how change it to open specific page on instagram app:

```
var url:String = ("intent:#Intent;" +
                  "action=android.intent.action.MAIN;" +
                  "category=android.intent.category.LAUNCHER;" +
                  "component=com.android.settings/.Settings;" +
                  "end");
navigateToURL(new URLRequest(url));
```

Comment: navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://stackoverflow.com"));

Comment: @Organis your code open a dialog box " complete action using" and show some application like chrome

Comment: That's normal behavior for opening **any** links on mobile devices, I guess.

Comment: In case of running a specific app you probably need this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22520218/opening-another-android-app-in-a-new-window-from-air

Comment: @Organis i dont want open a link !!! i want open "mypage" in Instagram app

Comment: @Organis in that answer, there is a package name and activity name parameter, what should i write for them?

Comment: How could I know? It's possible you're the first one to do that with Instagram. Figure out the details, that's what **developer** is about, Google, read the manuals, unpack Instagram installation and read the descriptor XML, anything else.

Comment: @Fanous see if this [**`Answer`**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21505941/intent-to-open-instagram-user-profile-on-android) gives you some hints about setting up your `url` string. There's also the Instagram developers guide to check what's [**`allowed for Android`**](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/android-intents/)... _"How change it to open specific page on instagram app?"_ check : Does Instagram app even allow such a specific thing (even if via `intent`) from outsider apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Share ANE](https://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.Share) to do open the Instagram app to a specific page. The following works on Android and iOS:

```
var app:Application = new Application( "com.instagram.android", "instagram://" );

var options:ApplicationOptions = new ApplicationOptions();
options.action = ApplicationOptions.ACTION_VIEW;
options.data = "http://instagram.com/_u/distriqt";
options.parameters = "user?username=distriqt";

if (Share.service.applications.isInstalled( app ))
{
    Share.service.applications.launch( app, options );
}
```

*I'm one of the developers of this ANE.*

Comment: Awesome products, because of ios support.

Comment: oh very nice, but its not free ! :(

Comment: Unfortunately not.. we put a lot of work into our extensions so it's just not possible for them to be free.

Answer (score 1):

You have to choose Air Native Extension (ANE),
that's very simple, first verify that Instagram is Installed, then just write native codes for that purpose and let AIR communicate between AS3 and Android machine.

the native code could be Java (for Android) and Objective-c (for IOS)

for beginning take a look at [this official tutorial](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/building-ane-ios-android-pt3.html)
also there is another [Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/air_extensions.pdf) around ANE

Comment: @Fanous فانوس؟ - thats not so hard, just search some codes for opening an instagram page within its app trough android, and just read included tutorial. humm but it takes huge time if you dont have Android sdk

Comment: تشکر از شما ، در این خصوص خیلی سرچ کردم ، ولی چیزی دستگیرم نشد . چون با جاوا آشنایی ندارم

Comment: @Fanous i'll do this for you if i found a time (maybe).